# `pandas` datetime - correct way to do linear interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, interpolation

FYI: `pandas` version is 1.3.4 for now

I have currently working code to interpolate non-monotonous timestamps (along with various other data not sampled monotonously) into a dataframe `out` with a monotonous (float-type) time `index`.  The important part is here:

```
out = out.join(dateTime_df.astype('int64'), 
               how = 'outer',
               ).interpolate(method = 'linear',  
                             limit_area = 'inside',
                             ).loc[index]  #`index` is the monotonous time index
out["DateTime_col"] = out["DateTime_col"].astype('<M8[ns]')
```

This currently works, but throws a `FutureWarning`:

```
FutureWarning: casting datetime64[ns] values to int64 with .astype(...) is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use .view(...) instead.
```

I'm wondering what the "right" way to do this would be, using `.view()`, as it doesn't seem like `DataFrame` has a `view` method (at least in my ancient `pandas` version 1.3.4 I'm stuck with for now).  I'm somewhat afraid to update my `pandas` version until I have a fix.

Edit: adding test data:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), 
                   columns = ['previously', 'imported', 'data'])
dateTime_df = pd.DataFrame([datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1), 
                            datetime.datetime.now()], 
                           index = [3, 7], 
                           columns = ["DateTime_col"])
index = np.arange(10)
```

Comment: Why not use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)? It can also handle Unix time as input.

Comment: For the back-conversion?  No idea.  `to_datetime` is probably better than what is there.

Comment: Try `dateTime_df.apply(lambda s: s.view('int64'))`, for `.view(...)` only exists on `Series`.

Comment: What I think the warning is trying to tell you is that `astype` is not intended as a type converter here (integer -> datetime). But I don't think a view is what you want if the resulting column should be of type datetime. So I'd go with to_datetime ;-)

Comment: I mean, the warning is pretty clear that the problem is in the other direction: `casting datetime64[ns] values to int64 with .astype(...) . . . `

Comment: @ChrisFu that seems to work.  Feel free to write an answer if you think it's generally useful (I know this is pretty old syntax)

Comment: interestingly, with pandas v2, I don't get any warning. However, using `astype` to convert from datetime to int is perfectly fine. Datetimes are represented internally with an integer anyways. The conversion back to datetime with `to_datetime` is more concise in my eyes. This does involve some calculations, so it's not a simple mapping and I would therefore assume `astype` to be not well-suited.

Comment: btw. `Series.view` is deprecated in pandas v2.2 - [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) suggest `astype`. That explains why I didn't see warnings. I'd still use to_datetime for conversion from int to datetime for clarity.